# (Windows 8 Javascript) WinJS.xhr does not reflect changes from api

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, winjs

I am developing an app, where I access photos from an slr via a wifi-sd-card. Right now, I am trying to retrieve the html response from a particular location on the camera and retrieve all the images' file names. Everything went okay, I am retrieving an html response; however, it does not update. I am receiving the same response over and over again (even if I delete or take new photos).

Been stuck with this problem for days now. Hope someone could help me out. Here's my code:

```
function retrieveImgFileNames() 
{
    var url = "http://my-sd-card-host:port/path";
    WinJS.xhr({ url: url, responseType: "text" })
    .done(function (r) {
        var doc = document.createElement("html");
        doc.innerHTML = r.response;
        var links = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")
        var imgs = [];
        var imgCount = 0;
        var notImg = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            var fileName = links[i].getAttribute("href");
            if (fileName.substring(fileName.length - 3, fileName.length) == 'JPG') {
                imgs.push(fileName);
                imgCount++;
            }
            else {
                notImg.push(fileName);
            }
        }

    }, function (r) {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Sorry. :( Error: " + r.statusText;
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help your particular problem, but you might try your code with the Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient class instead of WinJS.xhr.

Comment: Hi Eric, tried HttpClient but still get the same results. I also tried accessing a simple web app from a remote computer, instead of the wifi sd card. I put a button in my interface to GET response from the web app. As I have observed from my console, the command GET only happens once, no matter how many clicks I did on the button. Any idea why this is happening? :|

Comment: Due to changes of requirement, I switched to WP8 development, and still met the same problem. I solved this by adding an optional paramater in my url as shown [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/21dafb96-b031-47d3-b2bf-7e281c123f79/how-to-ignore-web-content-cache-in-windows-phone-8?forum=wpdevelop)

Apparently, the web content is being cached by default. Any good article about this?

Comment: Wow, that's great to know. We don't have any articles about that yet, but I'll keep it in mind. Thank you for the feedback, Joe!

I'll test that in a Windows Store app and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and add a `If-Modified-Since` header with a low value like `Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT`.

Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868281.aspx